# Visual Studio 2017 exits with "Unkown error" - doesn't run as non-administrator

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I've just installed VS 2017 on my machine. However when I try to start it right after the splash screen shows up a window popup appears stating "Unknown Error." and that's it.

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem when I run it under a user account. Worked fine after using an Administrator account.

Comment: Any chance to run it as unprivileged user? Our security  policy gives us restrictions and therefore or accounts aren't administrators.

Comment: I just ran over a thread at Microsoft Developer Community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/19377/vs2017-would-not-start-under-a-non-administrator-u.html

After a clean install and cleanup of Local AppData and AppData VS 2017 ran without administrator privledges.

Answer (score 0):

The solution, provided by the [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/19377/vs2017-would-not-start-under-a-non-administrator-u.html) from KwaXi, worked for me:

- Close VS
- delete %AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio
- delete %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio
- try to launch VS.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Go to %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\
2. Find all folders of the form 15.0_[randomCharacters]
3. Delete privateregistry.bin from each folder found in step 2
4. Run Visual Studio as an admin

Answer (score -1):

I had a situation where it was failing on trying to load "ClassDesigner_REG_27921.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8.pkgdef", exiting with "Unknown error" (typical).

My solution was to re-run the installer (`vs_installer.exe`) found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer` (in my case), which showed an "update" button.  I think after installing 2017 I forgot to check for updates first. Do that before installing any extensions (which is what triggered it for me).

Comment: Reason to downvote a solution that worked for me?  Very odd.